# ASP.NET MVC 2 parameters throws JS error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My application works fine when I have only one parameter. 
e.g.

/Product/Index/2

/Report/Sales/08-2009

But it failes when I add one more part to the url. Let's say I want to add the end month-year parameter to the url routing. Mow it becomes:

/Report/Sales/05-2009/09-2009

I do get both parameters in my action method. I parse it and retrieve the data and pass the Model to the View. With this scenario it throws the client side JS error when I try to access any of the form elements. I get "object expected" error. The same view works fine using just first parameter. What could be the issues here?

I also loose the CSS styles when this error occurs.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any more information about what javascrpt is failing?  Posting code is helpful.  And how the data provided in the failing example differs from the one that works.  The more details the better chance someone will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I got my answer as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, without seeing any code at all this is difficult to troubleshoot, but I'd say it's likely because you are referencing your javascript and css files using a relative path like:

> ../content/scripts/myjavascript.js

Adding the second url parameter has caused the browser to be unable to find the urls because you have added what *looks like* an extra level of depth to the url.

You should provide absolute urls to your scripts and css files. An easy way to do this is to use the "ResolveUrl" method like so:

```
<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Scripts/myjavascript.css") %>
```